# Angular 2 access header informations from get request

Tags: angular, get

An restservice provides Header Information in a get request. How can I access them through the response?

I only get these header informations in my response:

```
Array[3]
   0:{"content-type" => Array[1]}
   1:{"access-control-allow-origin" => Array[1]}
   2:{"access-control-allow-credentials" => Array[1]}

// Angular request
this._http.get("http://anyUrl/restservice/list")
  .map((response:Response) => {
    console.log(response);//<-- gives the above information but nothing more
    return response.json();
  });
```

Comment: In your `map()`, try reading `response.headers` instead of `response.json()`.

Comment: If you don't see what you're looking for inside the `response` object, it probably means it isn't there in the first place (i.e. the server is not setting the headers you want). I don't think Angular cleans up the response before handing it over to you. Try running the same request with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and see if you get different headers.

Comment: I can see in chrome development tools that there are more headers than the ones from the response. Maybe the .map operation does any kind of filter?

Comment: I can't reproduce it: get all headers in response. What is your final goal, to get some specific header?

Comment: Strange... In your example, you log before `map()` doesn't anything so that's not it. Are you sure you only see 3 members when you `console.log(response.headers)`?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it´s an CORS issue. We are checking this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to add "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" to your header information in your api. As jigar gala only referenced a link I post this as a new Response to have this clear.

```
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Custom-header");
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already raised on github.

check https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237